# Multiple Resolvers in Gradle build: cgilib not resolved

Tags: maven, ivy, artifactory, build.gradle

For a project, we have a dependency on our custom jar file which is hosted on Artifactory repository and other third party jars like junit ,cglib,asm etc.

In the gradle build, I have

```
resolve {
 contextUrl = "artifactory server"
 repository {
     repoKey = 'reponame'  //The Artifactory repository key to publish to
     username = 'user'             //The publisher user name
     password ='pass'           //The publisher password
      }
}
```

This works fine and resolves it,but the cglib is not resolved.So I tried to use 
mavenCentral() for that.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies { classpath group: 'cglib', name:'cglib-nodep' , version:'2.1'}
}
```

But still its not able to resolve it.I added another resolver like :

```
resolve {
contextUrl="http://repo1.maven.org"
repository {
  repoKey = "maven2"
}
```

Now it appends maven central address to even my artifactory resolver like

> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/artifactoryurl..

Is there any where I can have two different resolvers?

And also why is junit resolved automatically,but not cglib and asm.

Ps: I am new to gradle and have read almost the whole documentation.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please describe the error you get when trying to resolve cglib

Comment: I am simply getting could not resolve dependency for cglib @JBaruch